# PDF.js in javascript getTextContent returning wrong special characters

Tags: unicode, pdf.js

I'm having a problem extracting text from a pdf using PDF.js. I'm using a PDF which contains some special characters, czech characters e.g. Č. or germans e.g. ß, ü, ä
All standard letters are beeing extracted correctly, but the czech or germans aren´t.
here is my code:
.....

```
    async function extractText(url){
       
        let pdf;
        pdf = await pdfjsLib.getDocument(url).promise;
        //console.log(pdf);
        let pages = pdf.numPages;
        let meta = await pdf.getMetadata();
        for(let i=1;i<=pages;i++){
            let page = await pdf.getPage(i);

            let txt = await page.getTextContent();
            console.log(txt);

            let text = txt.items.map((s)=>s.str).join("");
            console.log(text);
            let utf = txt.items.map((s)=>encoder.encode(s.str)).join("");
            allText.push(text);
        }
    }
```

e.g.
ČSOB becomes something like: str: "ý62%\u0003D\u0011V\u0011\u0003\u0003.......

unicode problem?
Language?
what should I do?